# How to apply if statement for page

Tags: twig, octobercms

I have group of divs and tried this if statement in October CMS `{% if 'product' | page %} do something {% endif %}` does not work. Can anyone advice me the correct method?

Comment: I mean, what are you trying to achieve here? What does `{{ 'product'|page}}` output?

Comment: I want it to check if the user is on product page than show the div content

Comment: That is not what the filter `page` does though

Comment: you can use `{% if this.page.id == 'product' %} do something {% endif %}`